# Can you leave the UK from a visitor's visa and return immediately on a work visa?

Tags: visas, uk, pakistani-citizens

My fiance is a Pakistani citizen who is here to be with me in the UK on a visitor's visa. He works as a cardiac physiologist and so is in high demand; at the moment he is still in the process of receiving a work visa from his employer. However, I am pregnant and we have heard that it is very difficult to simply leave and then return immediately on his new visa. We are very worried he won't be here for his daughter's birth. Is the information we received correct, or will he be able to leave for a week and then return on the new work visa?
Any and all answers are appreciated, as we are desperate. Thank you.

Comment: "**He works** [...] **is still in the process of receiving a work visa**" Do you mean he's working in the UK at the moment? If he does, that is NOT good.

Comment: Also you don't get a work visa from your employer, but from the UK visa application centre, and the applicant cannot be inside the UK whilst applying, unless they're merely switching (which cannot be done if the original visa in a visit visa)

Comment: @Coke "he works as X" generally means that he habitually engages in profession X.  If he were working in the UK at the moment, it should be "he is working...."

Comment: @Coke also, with regard to your second comment, that's precisely the reason for this question. She knows her husband will have to leave the country to get the work visa, and she's worried that he'll be stuck outside the country when their child is born.  But this question really belongs on [Expatriates.SE].